# How to order a list of objects in dynamic memory, using a generic vector in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a vector class template, which has a member function that takes a pointer to a function:

```
template <class T>
void VecGenerico<T>::order(int fin, bool (*compare)(T,T)) //orders the vector
{
    for (int i=0;i<fin;i++)
    { 
         for (int j=i;j<fin;j++)
         {
               if ((*compare)(vector[i],vector[j])) //generic procedure
                   swap(vector[i],vector[j]);
         }
    }
}
```

I use the vector class in another class, called `Tienda` (shop):

```
 IN Tienda.h
 ...
 private:
        VecGenerico<Articulo*> lista; //Articulo is an abstract class
        int indice; //index
 ...

 IN Tienda.cpp
 ...
 Tienda::Tienda() : lista(20)
 {
     indice = 0;
 }

 bool Tienda::compareArticulos(Articulo* aux, Articulo* aux2) 
 {
    if (*aux > *aux2)
        return true;
    return false;
 }

 void Tienda::mostrar_articulos() //shows the list of objects after being ordered
 {
    lista.order(indice,*compareArticulos,?,?); // fix
    for (int i=0;i<indice;i++)
        lista[i]->mostrar_articulo();
  }
```

How do I correctly pass `compareArticulos` to `lista.order()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `order` member function (which should really be called `sort` for consistency), you define `compare` as a function pointer:

```
template <class T>
void VecGenerico<T>::order(int fin, bool (*compare)(T,T))
```

However, the comparator you want to pass in is a *member function*:

```
bool Tienda::compareArticulos(Articulo* aux, Articulo* aux2)
```

You cannot convert a member function to a function pointer. However, nothing in `compareArticulos` references `this` in any way, so one solution would be to simply make it `static`. A `static` member function can be converted to a function pointer. That way, you could do:

```
lista.order(indice, compareArticulos);
```

More generally, you should prefer to take any kind of comparator as an argument:

```
template <class T>
template <class Compare>
void VecGenerico<T>::order(int fin, Compare compare);
```

At which point, if you really required a member function comparator, you could do that too:

```
lista.order(indice, std::bind(&Tienda::compareArticulos, this));
```